# JsonConvert ignores DateTime Utc settings?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime, utc

I've some DateTime in this object of Kind Utc:

```
Model.Calendar
```

[image]

When I try to serialize it:

```
var calendar = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Calendar, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
  DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
}));
```

I see it ignores the DateTime Utc. Here's the console.log of calendar variable:

[image]

There is no +2.
When I take this object and I send back to backend, via the MVC Controller, the DateTime of the Calendar object is Kind Local:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCalendar")',
    data: { id: @Model.CalendarItem.ID, newCalendar: calendar, selectedMonth: $('.select-month').val() },
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function () {
        ShowLoading();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //
    },
    error: function (ex) {
        //
    },
    complete: function () {
        //
    }
});

public PartialViewResult UpdateCalendar(long id, List<List<CalendarDay>> newCalendar, int selectedMonth) {
     // here newCalendar's DateTime are Kind Local
}
```

is a problem with serialization I guess? How can I fix it?

Comment: Why would you expect a UTC `DateTime` value, serialized as UTC, to include a `+2` timezone offset? This sounds more like a deserialization problem.

Comment: @RichardDeeming do you mean while a receive the newCalendar object server side?

Comment: Yes. The data you're sending to the client and the settings you've shown look correct. The problem seems to be that the server is assuming that the values sent from the client are `Local` values instead of `Utc` values.

Comment: Personally, I'd be inclined to use `DateTimeOffset` instead, which should preserve the time-zone offset when you round-trip it to the client. Or switch to using NodaTime, which would be a much larger undertaking.

Comment: @RichardDeeming its the same problem also if I remove DateTimeOffset on serialization. How do I fix it server side?

Comment: It has nothing to do with json. Json serialize what it is already.  It just converts data to string. You have to convert the date to any format you like before serialization. You can even convert it to any string you like.

Comment: @markzzz `DateTimeOffset` has always worked for me. You could try changing the default JSON serializer settings in your app's startup: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;`

Comment: Can i change the default JSON settings only for that custom Controller? Not the whole app?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at your DateTime object and the json output, everything works as expected. You provided a UTC time for `2021-01-01 00:00:00` and that's what you've got by serializing it.

So you're actually looking to serialize it as a local time instead, like GMT+X ? As the comments already mentioned, there's no problem in json serialization, but in the way you provide the data to it. You should modify it to your requirements before serializing it.

Easiest way would be to parse it to an string with your desired output format (e.g. `ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZzzz")`)

Also kinda duplicate question as you've already asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69446032/2238110) which includes another way to use a custom JsonConverter/ActionFilter approach.