# How to set DateTime UTC while deserialize objects within a Controller's method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime, model-view-controller, deserialization, utc

I have this method within a controller on a ASP.NET MVC application:

```
public PartialViewResult UpdateCalendar(long id, List<List<CalendarDay>> newCalendar, int selectedMonth) {
    //
}
```

`CalendarDay` contains some DateTime objects. When I send them from Client, they are deserialized as Kind Local, and not Utc.

Example of Date received from client: `13/01/2022 00:00:00Z` (note the final Z; [I would expect Utc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597908/how-json-deserialize-datetime-and-convert-from-utc-to-a-specified-time-zone/51618873#51618873) as deserialization).

How can I setup (only for this controller/method; can't impact the whole app in the global config) the deserialization as Utc for the input object's DateTime?

Comment: Is this classic asp.net or core / 3 / 5 / 6 ?

Comment: A PartialViewResult usually sends data TO a client. Yet your question says from a client. If they are coming FROM a client, then a client might need to create them as utc and not as GMT+X. Otherwise your could simply iterate over your CalendarDay objects and call `.ToUniversalTime()`.

Comment: @Marco classic asp.net. The data from client is correct (not +X, as for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69437340/jsonconvert-ignores-datetime-utc-settings). The solution to iterate the date is a "workaround", and I don't like it so much. Any other way?

Comment: Do you want to convert your local Datetime to UTC Date time while perse from JSON to Data Model?

Comment: @Parvez no I need that the deserialization process save them in DateTime object with kind Utc (as they are), and not Local. By default it seems deserialization set Kind as Local

Comment: So, now your DateTime object represents local Datetime, which you want as UTC through the deserialization process, right?

Comment: @Parvez nope. It arrives as Utc to the server. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/122732958?noredirect=1, there is the screenshot with the DateTime format I have (which is Z). Its ISO 8601

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51618873/8112522
That's might help you

Comment: @Parvez nope. I have Z, but it doesn't deserialize to utc

Comment: @markzzz If your global config is set to parse datetimes as local in general (which is wrong IMHO), then you _have_ to use the workaround to convert them to UTC in your case.

Comment: @stackprotector I don't have any global settings :O

Comment: So basically everything is working, except you don't want to manually cast ToUniversalTime() for each object, right? By default the parameters will be parsed with local time for the controller action. But you could implement a [custom ActionFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1480429/2238110) to add custom json parsing (add custom [JsonConverter<DateTime>](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) which handles the UTC conversion for you) for your CalendarDay object.

Comment: @DanielD code example? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the default deserialization for your action parameters by either adding a custom ModelBinder (that changes deserialization everywhere the model is used) or for just that Controller Action with a custom ActionFilterAttribute.

So let's say we have this simple class

```cs
public class CalendarDay { public DateTime Date { get; set; } }
```

and your example date from above (`13/01/2022 00:00:00Z`)

Then add your custom implementation of the ActionFilter (could be just overwriting some values of already parsed ActionParameters or custom json deserialization, or anything else you like):

```cs
public class UtcDateTimeFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public string Parameter    { get; set; }
  public Type   JsonDataType { get; set; }

  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
    {
      string inputContent;
      filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      using (var sr = new StreamReader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream))
      {
        inputContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
      }

      var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(inputContent, JsonDataType, new CustomUtcDateTimeConverter());
      filterContext.ActionParameters[Parameter] = result;
    }
  }
}
```

> Hint: you can add some conditions for the JsonDataType to only add the CustomJsonConverter for certain types, to prevent UTC-converting every date you use the ActionFilter with. That way it's reusable for different cases.

As I've went with the custom json deserialization I can add a custom JsonConverter that automatically processes each occurence of my defined object (in this case the DateTime):

```cs
public class CustomUtcDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<DateTime>
{
  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
  }

  public override DateTime ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, DateTime existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
  {
    var date = DateTime.Parse((string)reader.Value);
    return date.ToUniversalTime();
  }
}
```

And finally you can define your Controller Action like this:

```cs
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[UtcDateTimeFilter(Parameter = "myUtcDates", JsonDataType = typeof(CalendarDay[]))]
public ActionResult TestUtcDateTimeDeserialization(CalendarDay[] myUtcDates)
{
    var date1 = myUtcDates[0];
    var date2 = myUtcDates[1];
    return PartialView("SomePartialView");
}
```

Resulting in this DateTime object:

[image: DateTime Screenshot]